# TypeORM getManyAndCount() doesn't return relation data

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm very new to TypeORM and NestJs.

In this project i have an entity VehicleModel that has a ManyToOne relationship with VehicleBrand.

When i run getManyAndCount() on my query, i don't understand why i don't get the VehicleBrand data. I verified this by running getQuery and debugging the code.

In other entities with relantionsips this same code works normally:

```
    public async findAll(findDto: F): Promise<GenericPagedListDto<E>> {
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder('t');
    
    await this.createCriteria(query, findDto);

    if (findDto.page > 0) {
        query.skip((findDto.page - 1) * findDto.limit);
    }
    query.take(+findDto.limit);

    const sort = findDto.sort ? JSON.parse(findDto.sort) : undefined;
    if (sort) {
        Object.keys(sort).forEach((key) => {
           query.orderBy(`${!key.includes(".")?"t.":""}${key}`, sort[key]==="asc"?"ASC":"DESC");
        });            
    }
    
    const [list, total] = await query.getManyAndCount(); //<--- Here!

    return new GenericPagedListDto<E>(list, total);
}
```

This is my relation

vehicle-model.entity.ts:

```
@ManyToOne(() => VehicleBrand, vehicleBrand => vehicleBrand.vehicleModels)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'vehicle_brand_id' })
vehicleBrand: VehicleBrand;
```

vehicle-brand.entity.ts:

```
@OneToMany(() => VehicleModel, vehicleModel => vehicleModel.vehicleBrand)
vehicleModels: VehicleModel[];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Eager relations](https://typeorm.io/eager-and-lazy-relations) in this way:

```js
@OneToMany(() => VehicleModel, vehicleModel => vehicleModel.vehicleBrand, { eager: true })
vehicleModels: VehicleModel[];
```

With this, the relation is loaded.